# Syntax error on token "mkdirs", Identifier expected after this token

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting the create a directory programmaticly to build out the Android Photo Capture app [here](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/). I tried creating a class to create the directory before define the path, but Eclipse is throwing  the error `Syntax error on token "mkdirs", Identifier expected after this token.` Should I be running the mkdirs() code elsewhere in the file?

```
    public class PhotoCaptureExample extends Activity 
    {
         public class Dir
         {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DrawIn");
        folder.mkdirs();

         }

         protected Button _button;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have code  outside of any function.  That isn't legal, except for simple initializers.

Answer (score -2):

to create a directory, you could use

```
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DrawIn");

if(!myDirectory.exists()) {                                 
  myDirectory.mkdirs();
}
```

don't forget to add permission:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```